# Agrupar resultados mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando agrupar resultados de una tabla para que me sume todas las cantidades de un mismo modelo, pero no termino de entender muy bien como funciona.

Voy a intentar explicar lo que necesito a ver si soy capaz:
Tengo 2 tablas una que se llama pedidos y otra pedidos linea las uno con dos campos con el mismo valor en cada una. En Pedidos se llama id y en pedidos_linea se llama idpedido y es un campo numérico. En pedidos es un numero único, en pedidos_linea puede haber varios resultados que tengan idpedido con el mismo valor ( se usa para agregar varios registros a un pedido. ).
Por otro lado en pedidos guardo un registro de estado que se llama "estado" donde guardo el estado que tiene el pedido.
Dentro de "pedidos_linea" guardo un campo que se llama "cantidad" y otro que se llama "idcosa" que enlaza con otra tabla y me da el campo "talla", "color", "sexo", "material" y "temporada" de ese articulo.

El caso es que me gustaría saber la suma de la cantidad de artículos que tengo de todos los pedidos que tengan el *estado 1 en los que *idcosa sea igual

*Estado = tabla pedidos
*idcosa = tabla Pedidos_linea

ahora mismo tengo este codigo:

```
$CPedido = Consulta_Dinamica("Array","*","Pedidos","`estado` = '1' ");
 foreach($CPedido as $DPedido) { //creo un array con el listado de pedidos
$CDPedido = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Pedidos","`id` = '".$DPedido["id"]."' ");
$CLineasPedido = Consulta_Dinamica("Array","*","Pedidos_Linea","`idpedido` = '".$DPedido["id"]."' ORDER BY `lineanum` ASC "); 
}
```

Pero solo me saca los datos de un pedido y aparte no suma nada (algo obvio ya que solo tengo los datos de un único pedido y no hay nada que sumar).

¿Me podríais echar una mano? que estoy un poco perdido de la forma que podría hacerlo. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para guardar el id de los pedidos usados he usado este codigo:

```
$implode_arr = array();
$CidPedidos = mysqli_query($Conectar, 'SELECT id  FROM `Pedidos` WHERE `empresa` = '.$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'].' AND `estado` = 1');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($CidPedidos)) { $implode_arr[] = $row['id']; }
$Idpedidos = implode(',', $implode_arr);
```

no se si habrá forma de hacer este implode directamente en la consulta principal.

Comment: Hola, por favor reestructura tu pregunta para lograrte entender, estare aqui atento para poderte ayudar, por favor no trates de hacer dinamica tu pregunta con emojies, y comentarios extras, ve al grano amigo para entenderte.

Comment: @ByGroxD ¿Asi?.

Comment: @ByGroxD nunca he sabido como hacer para poner la estructura aqui? hay alguna forma con phpmyadmin para verla y pegarla?

Comment: @ByGroxD puesta la imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas un `SELECT` multi tabla y el uso de GROUP BY el cual sirve para agrupar el conjunto de resultados por una o más columnas, en este caso solo una `idpedido`.

```
SELECT COUNT(C.idpedido) cantidad, C.concepto FROM Pedidos_Linea C, Pedidos O WHERE (C.idpedido = O.id AND O.estado = 1) GROUP BY c.idpedido;
```

> Puede que quizá por error haya escrito algún nombre de columna o tabla mal, lo hice a memoria por favor revisa.

**UPDATE**

A petición del usuario que necesita mostrar el ID del pedido.

```
SELECT O.id, COUNT(C.idpedido) cantidad, C.concepto FROM Pedidos_Linea C, Pedidos O WHERE (C.idpedido = O.id AND O.estado = 1) GROUP BY c.idpedido;
```

Comment: Vale :) voy a probar.

Comment: Genial. Funciona perfectamente :) un millón de gracias

Comment: Una pequeña vuelta de tuerca mas... ¿si quisiera saber todos los id que se han usado? ¿como lo haría?

Comment: id de pedidos o id de los pedidos_linea

Comment: de los pedidos.

Comment: Listo, he actualizado mi respuesta.